# What is point of type casting?

Tags: java, casting

In this snippet of code:

```
c = (char)(c - 'A' + 'a');
```

Why do we need the `(char)`? That's type casting right?

Assume the `c` on the right side of the assignment statement is a capital letter. I assume we're doing Unicode addition and subtraction here.

This is the snippet from the Java book that I'm reading:

> When arithmetic is done on a char, it is first converted to the int
>   that represents it in the Unicode system. Subtracting ’A’ from a
>   variable c essentially asks “How far into the upper-case letters is
>   the character in c?” Adding ’a’ then yields the int that is the same
>   distance into the sequence of lower-case alphabetic character code.
>   The cast to char is needed because char is a special kind of int with
>   a more limited range of values. By using the cast, the programmer
>   acknowledges that he or she understands the special nature of the
>   assignment and expects the value to be in the correct range, 0 through
>   66535.

I don't understand the point of the `(char)` cast? What would be different if we didn't use the `(char)` cast? What is casting more generally?

Comment: In simple words : In java number 8 can be taken as a character and not integer .... so 8+8 may giv 88 and not 16 ... since 8 should be considered as integer for airthmetic operation ,, we type caste as `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char` is an [integral type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) in Java, and when you perform arithmetic the result is an `int` ([JLS-4.2.2. Integer Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) says, in part, *the numerical operators, which result in a value of type `int` or `long`* and adds that does include *the additive operators `+` and `-`*).

```
char c = 'A';
System.out.printf("'%c' = %d%n", c, (int) c);
int d = (c - 'A' + 'a'); // c - 65 + 97
System.out.printf("'%c' = %d%n", (char) d, d);
```

And I get

```
'A' = 65
'a' = 97
```

Comment: % marks a variable, c is for char, d for decimal, n for newline, the variables are provided in the same order as in the string as parameters in the end. For a list of things you can do in formats you can see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Also flags can be used in between the % and the variable type, eg. `%10d` would format a number so that it takes up 10 characters (filled with spaces or 0's)

Comment: So if I perform a + when any side of the + is a char type, it results in a value of type int?

Answer (score 7):

This is due to [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). Quoting the JLS [section 15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> The binary `+` operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>
> The binary `-` operator performs subtraction, producing the difference of two numeric operands.
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

The numeric promotion in this case is a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). Quoting [section 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules: 
>   
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

So in your example, the cast to `char` is necessary because the addition is performed on an `int` value, so the result is also of type `int`. To store this in a `char`, you need an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

All you do in programming is give values to variables. Those variables can be of different types. In the end everything is a number that is handled in a certain way or a sequence/set of number handled as one "entity". Variables of different types can take up a different amounts of space.

If you have 2 things handled in different ways and taking up different amounts of space, you need a well defined way to convert between the 2 things, this is done by casting and operators. An operator takes a number of inputs and gives an output. + and - usually take 2 inputs and give 1 back.

In your case you used operators that take chars, take their bits and use them as numbers and return you the resulting number as int. Then you need to convert that number back to a letter manually, because you could possibly lose bytes. Also the explicit cast here prevents mistakes from programmers who handle numbers and accidentally convert them to a letter, they are warned by the compiler. In the end it all comes down to the specifications which declare exactly what happens for each input type and each operator.

Most of the time casting is done to give you an intuitive and easy way of converting types, when there is such a way. Most of the times this is done with numbers, because the only difference is the amount of bites provided (byte, short, int, long) and sometimes the internal computation (float, double). In these cases cutting and rounding is easy to do and achieved by casting to a type with less bytes or a integer representation, and adding bytes or changing representation to decimal point is done by casting to a type with more bytes or a type with floating point representation.

On the other hand there are times when you want to treat one object as a more general case and cast it to a ancestor type (also called super-type etc.). Eg. when you sort objects you might not care about what exact type you're handling when you write a sorting algorithm.