# Special characters in Java. Can you use single quotes in this printf method call?

Tags: java

I'm reading a textbook on Java and I encountered this passage. I had some questions.

First, here are some special escaped characters that the book mentions.

```
’\n’ the newline character 
’\t’ the tab character
’\0’ the zero character
’\’’ the single-quote character 
’\"’ the double-quote character 
’\\’ the backslash character
```

No problem so far. Then it writes:

> Newline and tab characters are often used in building strings that
>   will be printed. For example, one might write
>
> `System.out.println ("Here’s a person:\t" + name + ’\t’ + age +`
>   `"\n\n");`

But then it writes:

> It would be better and safer to use "\t" instead of ’\t’ in the line
>   above. If you wrote
>
> ```
> System.out.println (age + ’\t’ + name);
> ```
>
> the age and tab characters would be added as ints, which is probably
>   not what the programmer intended. Writing
>
> ```
> System.out.println (age + "\t" + name);
> ```
>
> will cause both uses of the plus operator to be interpreted as
>   concatenations.

Why is the single quote usage around the tab character bad? I don't understand what the problem is or why it happens? Why is '\t' all of a sudden interpreted as an int by the Java interpreter?

Comment: Because `char` is an integral type. As I [explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34502642/2970947) already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` works differently depending on whether one of its arguments is `String` or not.  If one argument is a `String`, then the other argument is converted to a `String`, and `+` performs string concatenation.  But if neither argument is a `String`, then both arguments must be numbers, and the result is arithmetic addition.  `char` is a numeric type (`'\t'` has the value 9).

The confusion comes when multiple operands are strung together with `+`.  Consider this, where `int1` and `int2` are integer variables:

```
"String" + int1 + '\t' + int2
int1 + " String" + '\t' + int2
int1 + '\t' + "String" + int2
int1 + '\t' + int2 + "String"
```

`+` associates from left to right.  In the first expression, the program computes `"String" + int1` first, which means it converts the integer to a `String`, and the result is a string (call it `temp1`).  Then it computes `temp1 + '\t'`, and since `temp1` is a `String`, it will convert `'\t'` to a string (a string of one tab character) and concatenate.  The result is another string (call it `temp2`), and then the last `+` will convert `int2` to a `String` and concatenate `temp2` with it.

The second expression works similarly, since the leftmost `+` has one string operand.  That means all the `+` will be string concatenation operators.

The third expression is different, though.  The leftmost `+` is adding two integers (actually an `int` and a `char`), so the result will be the result of `int1 + 9`, an integer.  Then, since the next `+` has a `String` operand, that integer (`int1 + 9`) will be converted to a string and concatenated.  This results in a `String`, so the last `+` is also string concatenation, and `int2` is converted to a string.

In the last case, the first and second `+` are both integer addition.  So the result here is that `int1 + int2 + 9` is computed; then the result is converted to a string and concatenated with the string literal.

That's what I think the text is referring to.  Although the first example will work, it's accident-prone, because if you decide to redo the expression and eliminate the first string literal, the meanings of all the `+` operators will suddenly change to arithmetic addition.

Note that this applies only to the `+` operator.  That's the only operator that has this special overloading property.

Comment: ah interesting. You're also implying that '\t' is actually not a string but a char (integeral type) right?

Comment: Correct.  If it's in single quotes, it's a `char`.  If it's in double quotes, it's a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the tab that is the issue. The problem is of the surrounding types.

`'\t'` indicates a character t, and `"\t"` is a string of length one.

The problem they point out is surrounding type. Adding an integer to a string yields a concatenated string. Adding an integer to a character yields an integer.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `System.out.println ("Here’s a person:\t" + name + ’\t’ + age +  "\n\n");` it tells you ***It would be better and safer to use "\t" instead of ’\t’ in the line above.*** The reason is  `"Here’s a person:\t"` is String type and `’\t’` is character type.And opSerator '+' works well in String-and-String but not in String-and-character.
When you use `System.out.println (age + ’\t’ + name);`The '+' works with int-and-int(As you known, the character can be parsed to int type).
when you use `System.out.println (age + "\t" + name);` The '+' works as a String-connect operator.

Comment: Not quite right: operator `+` works perfectly fine when given `String` and `char` operands.  The problem comes when given a number and a `char`.  I think you understand the concept right, but your answer is confusingly worded.

Comment: You're right.Operator + works prefectly when given String and char operands.That's my wrong. And thank you for your advice for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Escape sequence when written in ' ' (single quotes) acts as a character. And every character has a corresponding ASCII value which is an int. So when you write System.out.println (age + ’\t’ + name); it sums up age and ASCII value of '\t'. Whereas when you write \t in " " (double quotes) it assumes it as a string but still can interpret it as an escape sequence.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside single quotes indicates char and when you add a char to int the result is also int. Whereas when you use + operator with any String it means you are concatenating.